# Storing list of objects in Flutter

Tags: sql, object, flutter, sqflite

I am making an app, which contains two basic classes let's say `Class1` and `Class2`. And in `Class1` I stored `List<Class2>` as attribute with other attributes. My question is how to store `List<Class2>` if I store some object of `Class1` in sqflite database. Is there a way that I can store a List of `Class2` objects in a single column of the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can serialize it to `json` and save the string. Then when you read it you can parse it back to an `Object`

Comment: You are saying that I should store objects in a file?

Comment: Nope, I'm saying you can store the list of objects parsed as `json` in a `TEXT` field of `SQFLITE`