# How to store a list of objects in sqflite?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, persistence, sqflite

I want to use the [`sqflite` package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to store my objects. I read some [articles](https://medium.com/pharos-production/using-sqflite-in-flutter-application-bc21bf446154), [tutorials](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite#7-update-a-dog-in-the-database) and [examples](https://camposha.info/flutter-sqflite-insertselectshow/) about it. So far I understand everything. But none of them covers my use case:

I have a class named `Foo`. This class holds beside some primitive fields an object of the class `Bar`. `Bar` has only primitive fields. Additionally `Foo` has a list of objects of the type `Baz`. `Baz` has also only primitive fields.

```dart
class Foo {
  // simple fields

  String id;

  Bar bar;
  List<Baz> bazs;
}

class Bar {
  // only primitive fields
  
  String id;
}

class Baz {
  // only primitive fields

  String id;
}
```

I want to connect the `bar` object with the `foo` object in the database and the same with the `bazs` objects. How do I do it? Whats the best way?

I'm not really experienced wit SQL. I know what SELECT, WHERE, ORDERBY and so on means but my knowledge does not get much further.

I found [this qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60267429/storing-list-of-objects-in-flutter) in Stack Overflow but I wonder if it is actually efficient to store all the values as a JSON. What happens if the JSON gets really big?

Currently my only idea is to store the `id` of the `bar` object as a field in the `foo` object or vica versa. `foo` could also hold a list of the `id`s of the `bazs` objects. Or each `baz` objects holds the `id` of the `foo` object. Is this a good solution?

Is there a possibility to let `sqflite` handle the relations between the objects?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create 3 tables:

1. Foos:
   [fields]:

- `id`

2. Bars:
   [fields]:

- `foo_id`: a foreign key that points to the `id` field of `Foo`
- `bar_id`: which is the bar's id

3. Bazs:
   [fields]:

- `foo_id`: a foreign key that points to the `id` field of `Foo`
- `baz_id`: which is the baz's id

Now lets say that you want fetch a `Foo` record with and Id = 3 along with the `bar` and `bazs`

1. fetch the foo record:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = 3;
```

2. fetch bar where `foo_id = 3`

```
SELECT bar_id
FROM bars
INNER JOIN Foo on B.id = bars.foo_id;
```

3. fetch bazs where `foo_id = 3`

```
SELECT baz_id
FROM bazs
INNER JOIN Foo on B.id = bazs.foo_id;
```

It would be easier if you use `moor` package to implement a sqllite DB